# Migrating from Ionic v1 to Ionic v3 or v4?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, cordova, ionic3

My Ionic v1 app needs to be upgraded to v3...or even v4.  A few questions:

> 1. In my v1 app, I have a root JS folder with app.js, controllers.js, services.js that all pages, templates pull from.  I know in Ionic
>      v2-v4, that each page has its own folder and its own
>      controller,service,template.html files - I will need to break everything apart and move it into the new structure.  However, in my v1 app I also
>      have a "global" index.js file for standard JS functions that I load
>      into my app via the main `index.html` file - the functions in this file are used heavily in all
>      pages/controllers/services of my existing app.  In the new structure,
>      where would I put this global "index.js" file - or, what should I
>      convert it to so all the functions remain global?
> 2. Is there some kind of matrix that shows `features` for v1, v2, v3 and v4 - what is the gain in each version, besides performance, over
>      the previous version (things you can do now that you could not do
>      previously)?
> 3. Is there a JS to TS migration tool that can help migrate all my existing JS?
> 4. And lastly, is there any argument in moving straight to v3 versus straight to v4?

There is always the "if it ain't broke don't fix it".  But I am finding it harder and harder to maintain my v1 app, harder to add new features, finding more and more plugins are not supported anymore and overall I believe there are major performance gains that migrating has now become a necessity.  I just loathe having to go through the process.

Comment: Please try to ask only one question at a time otherwise it'll be hard to answer and also hard to search for exact questions...

Comment: On your problem: There are migration guides for [moving to v2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjnsvfrx6HfAhXiAxAIHVRaALoQFjABegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fionicframework.com%2Ffiles%2FIonic2Migration.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0MRevCISQ32XKxb8RKQu_-) and [moving to v4](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration/). They normally compare features and guide you in migrating. As far as I know there is no tool to do this (as you already pointed out there were structural changes which make automation hard)

Comment: Lastly I would advise against migrating directly to v4 as long as it is still in beta... I'd either wait until v4 has it first stable release or migrate to the already stable v4. You can check out the latest releases [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases).

Answer (score 0):

Put the global JS tag in `src/index.html` header tag, before the  `build/polyfills.js` and `build/main.js` (they are in body tag).

Example : I created a file `src/assets/test.js` with a `var testvar`, imported in `src/index.html` and then in `src/app/app.component.ts` declared declare `var testvar;`.

**test.js**

```
var testvar = "Hello from external js";
```

**index.html**

```
...
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

      <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/test.js"></script> //here, not in body
...
```

**app.componet.ts**

```
...  
declare var testvar;

    @Component({
       templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {
      @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
      constructor(private statusbar : StatusBar,  splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
       alert(testvar);
...
```